# How to get thumbnail URL of the MS teams chatMessagehostedcontent image in MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm looking for getting thumbnail of the chatMessagehostedcontent image using MS graph APi.
Example: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}/hostedContents/{hostedcontntid}/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/%7BchatId%7D/messages/%7BmessageId%7D/hostedContents/%7Bhostedcontntid%7D/$value)
This URL returns the actual image content.
However I need only the thumbnail of this? How to retrieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Will repro and will inform you as soon as possible.

Comment: Could you please confirm are you able to get hostedContent Id for images?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported with hostedContents. You can fetch specific size image only for [profile photos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-2-get-the-48x48-photo-for-the-signed-in-user).